# ordenar as datas no banco

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, sqlite, classificação

Estou com o seguinte problema, não consigo ordenar por ordem crescente as datas que estão salvas no banco, estou usando o order by no select porem só ordena as duas primeiras casas ate chegar na / fazendo com que o mês fique bagunçado, meu projeto é android mas acredito que quem possui conhecimento com banco possa me ajudar, se alguém puder agradeço

atualmente eu fiz uma tabela no banco só para testar tabela agenda campo data = date

com as barras (05/01/2016)

ja tentei cadastrar a data sem as barras (05012016)

sem os 0 (512016)

sem os 0 com as barras (5/1/2016)

e para ordenar select * from agenda order by data

Comment: Adicione como está sua tabela, e como você já tentou fazer essa query, editando a pergunta.

Comment: Eu já me deparei com esse problema, acho que é problema do sqlite: ele trata o tipo data como um string ou similar por isso não da para ordenar. O que eu fiz foi ordenar no java, quando chegar em casa posto o codigo

Comment: As datas devem ser inseridas conforme o padrão: YYYY-MM-DD ou adicionando HH:MM:SS caso queira tempo. [Doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: eu usei esse padrao(YYYY-MM-DD ) no banco e deu certo, agora eu tenho que arrumar meu android studio q não esta aparecendo o emulador para eu poder testar, mas acredito que vai da tudo certo, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Victor, tente usar o `DESC`no `ORDER BY`.

Para decrescente:

```
select * from agenda order by  data desc;
```

Para crescente:

```
select * from agenda order by  data asc;
```

Comment: só consegui arrumar o erro quando mudei o formato de salvar a data, esse é o padrão que funciona (YYYY-MM-DD ), antes estava (DD/MM/YYYY) ai ele só ordenava as duas casas do dia

Comment: Vitor, qual o formato que você irá utilizar e qual o banco que esta rodando essa consulta?

Comment: o campo esta como date, o problema já foi resolvido !